# Weather and Traffic Webpart in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

Based on the location seleted from the map ,weather report for that specific location should be displayed using sharepoint 2010. Is there any plug ins or webpart available ??

Regards

Swetha S

Comment: try bing/google, there's load sof them out there...

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript/html to a page using SharePoints Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) so you can just find one of the dozens of online services that do this and use their javascript on your SharePoint page.